# Logging from pyspark

Tags: logging, apache-spark

The info on logging from pyspark found in this question [How to turn off INFO logging in PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-pyspark)  is not working for me: the logging is not happening.

I am familiar with setting up logging in pyspark from a locally built spark. I am however using the cloudera spark now. I have set a RollingFileAppender within the

```
$SPARK_HOME/log4j.properties
```

which is the correct thing to do according to the docs:

http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/configuration.html#configuring-logging

> ```
> Configuring Logging
> Spark uses log4j for logging. You can configure it by adding a
> ```
>
> log4j.properties file in the conf directory. One way to start is to
>   copy the existing log4j.properties.template located there.

But that is not taking effect:  no logging files are created in the destination directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the specific problem were due to one of the libraries Zookeeper does not use the setting for log4j.properties provided by SPARK_HOME. Instead ZK picks up the first log4j.properties on the classpath

The solution was to copy the log4j.properties already in the $SPARK_HOME/conf dir to the $HADOOP_CONF_DIR. Then the logging behaved as anticipated.