# How to avoid output stream of Python in Scala?

Tags: python, scala

I would like to initiate the spark context in python from scala.

I have added package 'pyspark' to do this. This is the code which I have tried and this works fine.

Code snippet:

```
import sys.process._

var os: java.io.OutputStream = _
val python = Process(Seq("python","-i")).run(BasicIO.standard(os = _))

def pushLine(s: String): Unit = {
  os.write(s"$s\n".getBytes("UTF-8"))
  os.flush()
}

pushLine("from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf;from pyspark.sql import SQLContext;conf = SparkConf().setAppName('test').setMaster('local');sc = SparkContext(conf=conf);sqlContext = SQLContext(sc);")
```

Now, my requirement is to avoid the output stream that gets displayed in scala. Is there any option to avoid this ?

[image: Spark Context Initialization]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-pyspark try this

Comment: Thanks for your reply @vijay..... I have modified the property **log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console** in log4j template, but still I could see the logs generated. Is there any other options available ?

Comment: copy log4j.properties.template to log4j.properties

Comment: did you tried my answer below?

Comment: yes, it works.... thanks @vijay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below method worked for me.

1. **create a file log4j.properties** in some directory say **/home/vijay/py-test-log**

   log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
   log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
   log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
   log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
   log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

   log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
   log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
   log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
   log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
2. **cd /home/vijay/py-test-log**  // log4j.props file should be here
3. then lauch pyspark from this directory in which u have log4j.properties

   **$pwd**
   /home/vijay/py-test-log
   **$/usr/lib/spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.3/bin/pyspark**
4. That all done. **pyspark will load the log4j.props file from where it is launched.**