# How to avoid console log info in Python?

Tags: python, logging, pyspark

I am using '**pyspark**' package to initialize spark context and when I do that, I could see lot of log info displayed. Is there any option / command available to avoid this ?

**Code snippet:**

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf;
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext;
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Stiffo.... I have modified the log4j.properties, but this stops displaying log info in spark scala shell too... Is there any other options available ?

Answer (score -1):

[Answer courtesy of user AkhlD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-pyspark/27815462#27815462):

Edit your conf/log4j.properties file and Change the following line:

```
   log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console
```

to

```
    log4j.rootCategory=ERROR, console
```

Another approach would be to :

Fireup spark-shell and type in the following:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

You won't see any logs after that.