# How to turn off INFO from logs in PySpark with no changes to log4j.properties?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I working in a cluster where I do not have the permission to change the file log4j.properties to stop the info logging while using pyspark (as explained in first answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-pyspark).) The following solution as explained in the above question's first answer work for spark-shell (scala)

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.log4j.Level
```

But for spark with python (ie pyspark), it didn't work nor the following

```
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```

How can I stop the verbose printing of info in pyspark WITHOUT changing log4j.properties file?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I used `sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")` because I didn't have write access to our cluster's log4j.properties file. From the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.setLogLevel):

> Control our logLevel. This overrides any user-defined log settings. Valid log levels include: ALL, DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, OFF, TRACE, WARN

Comment: Why does this solution not work for me?
sc.setLogLevel("Error")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        AttributeError: 'SparkContext' object has no attribute 'setLogLevel'

Comment: This didn't seem to affect the executor logging for me

Comment: Tried this but seems like it's not disabling log4j logs, I'm still seeing something like this even if I set log level to "OFF": Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
 at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
 at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)

Comment: @GalenLong I use pyspark with PYthon 3.4. I use dataframe which is implemented in Scala that's why I saw these scala log data.

Comment: Makes no difference for me

Comment: Does not work.  This does not seem to be the right answer.

Comment: For users of PySpark visiting this overflow, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40504350/2523501 for the answer.

Answer (score 7):

This helps for me:

```
import logging
s_logger = logging.getLogger('py4j.java_gateway')
s_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
spark_context = SparkContext()
```

Answer (score 4):

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208445/3811916:

```
logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger.LogManager.getLogger("org").setLevel( logger.Level.OFF )
logger.LogManager.getLogger("akka").setLevel( logger.Level.OFF )
```

does the trick for me. This is essentially how it's done within [PySpark's own tests](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.6.2/python/pyspark/tests.py#L316):

```
class QuietTest(object):
    def __init__(self, sc):
        self.log4j = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j

    def __enter__(self):
        self.old_level = self.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger().getLevel()
self.log4j.LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(self.log4j.Level.FATAL)
```