# pyspark disable logging to STDOUT

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging, pyspark

I have been using `PySpark` and have a problem with the logging. Logs from the `Spark` module are piped to STDOUT and I have no control over that from `Python`.

For example, logs such as this one are being piped to STDOUT instead of STDERR:

> 2018-03-12 09:50:10 WARN  Utils:66 - Truncated the string
>   representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be
>   adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.

`Spark` is not installed in the environment, only `Python` and `Pyspark`.

How do I:

**A. Redirect all logs to STDERR**

OR

**B. If that is not possible, disable the logs.**

---

Things I have tried:

1. I have tried to use the `pyspark.SparkConf()` but nothing I configure there seems to work.
2. I have tried creating `SparkEnv.conf` and setting the `SPARK_CONF_DIR` to match just to check if I could at least disable the example log above, to no avail.
3. I have tried looking at the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/configuration.html#configuring-logging) but no indication of how to accomplish what I am trying.

Comment: Or **C. Redirect everything to `/dev/null`?**

Comment: No, my program has actual STDOUT information that I want to display, these logs should not be going to STDOUT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set Log Level to ERROR, so it will only show ERROR logs:

```
sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")  # sc is a SparkContext() object from the pyspark lib
```

But if you want to disable all PySpark logs you can do this:

```
sc.setLogLevel("OFF")
```

Check this [Stack Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512684/how-to-turn-off-info-from-logs-in-pyspark-with-no-changes-to-log4j-properties/36408082)

Comment: I am sorry, but where is `sc` object defined? what is it?

Comment: The sc object is the SparkContext. If you are using PySpark integrated with some IDE, automatically it starts a new spark context and provides you a SparkContext object named sc, and a SparkSession named spark. If you are not using PySpark integrated, and maybe importing libraries by hand, the sc object I refer is the object that you create with SparkContext() or SparkContext.getOrCreate() or similar instructions.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, I have been doing it manually. It seems to solve my problem. Thanks a bunch.