# Unable to enable INFO logging for pyspark job

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, log4j

Need to enable INFO logging for detail information but only able to capture error and warn.

> log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console, server, file
>      log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
>       log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
>       log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>       log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %c{1}: %m%n
>
> # Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
>       log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=WARN
>       log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
>       log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
>       log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
>
> log4j.appender.server=org.apache.log4j.net.SocketAppender
>       log4j.appender.server.Port=4712
>       log4j.appender.server.RemoteHost=
>       log4j.appender.server.ReconnectionDelay=10000
>
> #log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
>       log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
>       log4j.appender.file.File=/data/sourav/logs/ServiceReminder.log
>       log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
>       log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
>       log4j.appender.file.Threshold=debug
>       log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>       log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %5p %c{7} - %m%n
>
> log4j.logger.org.apache.spark=INFO
>       log4j.logger.org.eclipse.jetty=INFO
>       log4j.logger.com.vmeg.code=${vm.logging.level}
>
> log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
>       log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO

PFB the code snippet.

```
log4jLogger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
LOGGER = log4jLogger.LogManager.getLogger(__name__)

LOGGER.info("pyspark script testing INFO")
LOGGER.warn("pyspark script testing WARN")
LOGGER.error("pyspark script testing ERROR")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `LOGGER.setLevel("INFO")` should suffice

Answer (score 0):

In the scala api, you would have:

```
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("INFO")
```

somewhere in your job. Perhaps the python api is the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36408082/2639647).

Answer (score 0):

I put a simple solution as a comment. However, there are different applications that log info. So, you could be more granular and set different levels for each. Example:

```
logManager = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j.LogManager

logManager.getLogger("org.apche").setLevel(Level.INFO)
logManager.getLogger("org.apache.spark").setLevel(Level.WARN)
logManager.getLogger("org.spark-project").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
```