# Disabling INFO logging in PySpark

Tags: logging, apache-spark, pyspark

I've edited the `log4j.properties` file to set `log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console`and the logging has stopped in spark-shell but it is unrelenting in pyspark.

The below code is working for me in pyspark. However I need to set it every time I open the pyspark console.

```
logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger.LogManager.getLogger("org").setLevel( logger.Level.OFF )
logger.LogManager.getLogger("akka").setLevel( logger.Level.OFF )
```

I'm looking for a permanent fix for this issue and want to understand how pyspark alone is picking up the default properties when spark-shell is not. I've checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-pyspark) thread but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
sc.setLogLevel("OFF")
```

Which means you need to set the log level `OFF` using spark context object.