# How to suppress garbage collection output in spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit

When submitting jobs via spark-submit, the console scrolls with the output below. 
How can this be disabled?

```
63.864: [GC 2382251K->1247626K(3637248K), 0.0089420 secs]
64.370: [GC 2404234K->1259517K(3636736K), 0.0090540 secs]
```

The python script prints other [useful] output that I want to focus on.

Comment: Have you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26123496/6138873 ?

Comment: Have tried modifying settings with SparkContext, but this isn't having any impact on the garbage collection output described above.  I don't have access to modify the configuration directly.