# Turn off pyspark logging through python sript

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How can I turn off pyspark logging from a python script?
Pls Note : I do not want to make any changes in the spark logger properties file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove (or modify) logging from a python script:

```python
conf = SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.logConf', 'true')  # necessary in order to be able to change log level
... # other stuff and configuration

# create the session
spark = SparkSession.builder\
    .config(conf=conf) \
    .appName(app_name) \
    .getOrCreate()

# set the log level to one of ALL, DEBUG, ERROR, FATAL, INFO, OFF, TRACE, WARN
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")
```

[docs configuration](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html)

[docs setLogLevel](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.SparkContext.setLogLevel)

Hope this helps, good luck!

**Edit**: For earlier versions, e.g. 1.6, you can try something like the following, taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208445/3433323)

```python
logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger.LogManager.getLogger("org"). setLevel(logger.Level.OFF)
# or
logger.LogManager.getRootLogger().setLevel(logger.Level.OFF)
```

I haven't tested it unfortunately, please, let me know if it works.

Comment: I am working on spark 1.6, which doesnt support SparkSession :( Could you  pls suggest some other solution.

Comment: @eiram_mahera edited the answer, let me know if it works for you :)