# Turn off logging for Spark 2.0 +

Tags: python, apache-spark, logging, pyspark

I did follow this existing [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-pyspark/32208445#32208445), though that the accepted answer works if Spark has been installed from the source.

However, I installed `pyspark` via `pip` as a result I am unable to locate the `conf/log4j.properties.template` in order to mute the logging info.

I am using the following alternate solution from the same link:

```
def quiet_logs( sc ):
  logger = sc._jvm.org.apache.log4j
  logger.LogManager.getLogger("org"). setLevel( logger.Level.ERROR )
  logger.LogManager.getLogger("akka").setLevel( logger.Level.ERROR )
```

The above solution still allows the logs from the start-up and closing down Spark info on the terminal, which does not happen if I am able to update `conf/log4j.properties.template`.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can override default log4j configuration for pyspark when invoking the command, you don't need to modify global files. Create a file with name `log4j-quiet.properties` and content:

```
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
```

Then start pyspark with:

```
$ pyspark --driver-java-options '-Dlog4j.configuration=file:log4j-quiet.properties'
```

And logging messages from startup and closing down will gone.