# Remove warnings and logging in minimal pyspark unit test

Tags: python, testing, pyspark

I am writing a set of unit tests for some library that depends and uses PySpark. For that, I am using something like this:

```
import unittest

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import Row


class PySparkTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(cls):
        conf = pyspark.SparkConf().setMaster('local[1]').setAppName("testing")
        cls.spark = pyspark.SQLContext(pyspark.SparkContext(conf=conf))

    def tearDown(cls):
        cls.spark._sc.stop()

    def test_basic(self):
        instance = self.spark.createDataFrame(data=[Row(a=1.0, b='s'), Row(a=1.0, b='s')])
        self.assertEqual(instance.count(), 2)
```

and executing (`Python 3.7.0`, `pyspark==2.3.1`), as

```
python -m unittest example
```

The test passes but with one log message and 2 warnings:

> 2018-09-08 12:14:15 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load
>   native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes
>   where applicable
>
> Setting default log level to "WARN".
>
> To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use
>   setLogLevel(newLevel).
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py:839:
>   ResourceWarning: subprocess 13349 is still running   ResourceWarning,
>   source=self)
>
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219:
>   ImportWarning: can't resolve package from `__spec__` or `__package__`,
>   falling back on `__name__` and `__path__`   return f(*args, **kwds)
>
> .
>
> ---
>
> Ran 1 test in 16.361s
>
> OK

1. Should I be worried about any of this?
2. If not, how do I suppress this text from showing up?

Comment: This particularly is a warning so you shouldn't be worried about it, regarding how you could suppress this text, this thread may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-spark

Comment: you have your answer i suppose, right?

Comment: @user2906838, thanks. I know about that question. However, 1. the answer to that question relies on changing spark config, which I do not have access to in general and affects all users (including a non-testing env). 2. It does not address the other 2 warnings.