# Spyder IDE with PySpark shows keeps logging everything in spite of turning off INFO to WARN

Tags: python, pyspark, anaconda, spyder, apache-spark-xml

I followed this [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-spark) to turn off log4j INFO logging but I still see this huge level of logs in my Spyder IDE's console.

[image]

I don't want to see even these warnings. show just the errors generated by my script.
=> I am launching spyder from anaconda and using Pyspark api set.