# spark-submit How to pass argument to jar mentioned in --jar?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-submit, spark-java

I have a PySpark project where to log microbatch metrics, we have a jar which is passed using --jars, it works but I need to add a on/off switch for logging. How can I pass this on off switch when running using spark submit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to turn off INFO logging in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25193488/how-to-turn-off-info-logging-in-spark)

Comment: Won't work! as I am using cloudwatch to log some data -
Ex.   metricsLogger.putMetric("addBatch", progressEvent.durationMs().get("addBatch"), Unit.MICROSECONDS);