# Where are the spark intermediate files stored on the disk?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

During a shuffle, the mappers dump their outputs to the local disk from where it gets picked up by the reducers. Where exactly on the disk are those files dumped? I am running pyspark cluster on YARN.

What I have tried so far:

I think the possible locations where the intermediate files could be are (In the decreasing order of likelihood):

1. `hadoop/spark/tmp`. As per the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html) at the `LOCAL_DIRS` env variable that gets defined by the yarn.
   However, post starting the cluster (I am passing `master --yarn`) I couldn't find any `LOCAL_DIRS` env variable using `os.environ` but, I can see `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` which should happen only in case of mesos or standalone as per the documentation (Any idea why that might be the case?). Anyhow, my `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` is `hadoop/spark/tmp`
2. `tmp`. Default value of `spark.local.dir`
3. `/home/username`. I have tried sending custom value to `spark.local.dir` while starting the pyspark using `--conf spark.local.dir=/home/username`
4. `hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir`. This is the value of `yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs` property in yarn-site.xml

I am running the following code and checking for any intermediate files being created at the above 4 locations by navigating to each location on a worker node.

The code I am running:

```
from pyspark import storagelevel
df_sales = spark.read.load("gs://monsoon-credittech.appspot.com/spark_datasets/sales_parquet")
df_products = spark.read.load("gs://monsoon-credittech.appspot.com/spark_datasets/products_parquet")
df_merged = df_sales.join(df_products,df_sales.product_id==df_products.product_id,'inner')
df_merged.persist(storagelevel.StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
df_merged.count()
```

There are no files that are being created at any of the 4 locations that I have listed above

As suggested in one of the answers, I have tried getting the directory info in the terminal the following way:

1. At the end of log4j.properties file located at `$SPARK_HOME/conf/` add `log4j.logger.or.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer=INFO`
   This did not help. The following is the screenshot of my terminal with logging set to INFO

[image]

Where are the spark intermediate files (output of mappers, persist etc) stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into the weeds of Spark source, perhaps you can quickly check it live. Something like this:

```
>>> irdd = spark.sparkContext.range(0,100,1,10)                                                                                                          
>>> def wherearemydirs(p):
...   import os
...   return os.getenv('LOCAL_DIRS')                                                                                                
... 
>>> 
>>> irdd.map(wherearemydirs).collect()
>>>
```

...will show local dirs in terminal

/data/1/yarn/nm/usercache//appcache/<application_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxx>,/data/10/yarn/nm/usercache//appcache/<application_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxx>,/data/11/yarn/nm/usercache//appcache/<application_xxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxx>,...

But yes, it will basically point to the parent dir (created by YARN) of UUID-randomized subdirs created by `DiskBlockManager`, as @KoedIt mentioned:

```
:
23/01/05 10:15:37 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /data/1/yarn/nm/usercache/<your-user-id>/appcache/application_xxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxx/blockmgr-d4df4512-d18b-4dcf-8197-4dfe781b526a
:
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the directory this way. Instead of printing the dirs name and then trying to see them through the logs I returned the value of LOCAL_DIRS from wherearemydirs and used map on the rdd. Making that edit to the answer since that seems a rather more straightforward way to get to the answer. Please change back if I am mistaken in doing so

Comment: Thanks @dont_stop_believing! I'd maybe use mapPartitions instead of simply map, but other than that it looks excellent!

Answer (score 1):

This is going to depend on what your cluster setup is and your Spark version, but you're more or less looking at the correct places.

For this explanation, I'll be talking about Spark v3.3.1. which is the latest version as of the time of this post.

There is an interesting method in `org.apache.spark.util.Utils` called [`getConfiguredLocalDirs`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L932-L965) and it looks like this:

```scala
  /**
   * Return the configured local directories where Spark can write files. This
   * method does not create any directories on its own, it only encapsulates the
   * logic of locating the local directories according to deployment mode.
   */
  def getConfiguredLocalDirs(conf: SparkConf): Array[String] = {
    val shuffleServiceEnabled = conf.get(config.SHUFFLE_SERVICE_ENABLED)
    if (isRunningInYarnContainer(conf)) {
      // If we are in yarn mode, systems can have different disk layouts so we must set it
      // to what Yarn on this system said was available. Note this assumes that Yarn has
      // created the directories already, and that they are secured so that only the
      // user has access to them.
      randomizeInPlace(getYarnLocalDirs(conf).split(","))
    } else if (conf.getenv("SPARK_EXECUTOR_DIRS") != null) {
      conf.getenv("SPARK_EXECUTOR_DIRS").split(File.pathSeparator)
    } else if (conf.getenv("SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS") != null) {
      conf.getenv("SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS").split(",")
    } else if (conf.getenv("MESOS_SANDBOX") != null && !shuffleServiceEnabled) {
      // Mesos already creates a directory per Mesos task. Spark should use that directory
      // instead so all temporary files are automatically cleaned up when the Mesos task ends.
      // Note that we don't want this if the shuffle service is enabled because we want to
      // continue to serve shuffle files after the executors that wrote them have already exited.
      Array(conf.getenv("MESOS_SANDBOX"))
    } else {
      if (conf.getenv("MESOS_SANDBOX") != null && shuffleServiceEnabled) {
        logInfo("MESOS_SANDBOX available but not using provided Mesos sandbox because " +
          s"${config.SHUFFLE_SERVICE_ENABLED.key} is enabled.")
      }
      // In non-Yarn mode (or for the driver in yarn-client mode), we cannot trust the user
      // configuration to point to a secure directory. So create a subdirectory with restricted
      // permissions under each listed directory.
      conf.get("spark.local.dir", System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")).split(",")
    }
  }
```

This is interesting, because it makes us understand the order of precedence each config setting has. The order is:

- if running in Yarn, `getYarnLocalDirs` should give you your local dir, which depends on the `LOCAL_DIRS` environment variable
- if `SPARK_EXECUTOR_DIRS` is set, it's going to be one of those
- if `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` is set, it's going to be one of those
- if `MESOS_SANDBOX` and `!shuffleServiceEnabled`, it's going to be `MESOS_SANDBOX`
- if `spark.local.dir` is set, it's going to be that
- ELSE (catch-all) it's going to be `java.io.tmpdir`

**IMPORTANT**: In case you're using Kubernetes, all of this is disregarded and [this logic](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/resource-managers/kubernetes/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/k8s/features/LocalDirsFeatureStep.scala#L42-L72) is used.

#### Now, how do we find this directory?

Luckily, there is a nicely placed logging line in [`DiskBlockManager.createLocalDirs`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/fbbcf9434ac070dd4ced4fb9efe32899c6db12a9/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/DiskBlockManager.scala#L253) which prints out this directory if your logging level is INFO.

So, set your default logging level to INFO in log4j.properties ([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26123496/15405732)), restart your spark application and you should be getting a line saying something like

> `Created local directory at YOUR-DIR-HERE`

Comment: thank you for your reply :)
Unfortunately, setting the logging level with ```spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('INFO')``` is not helping. There is no additional info that is getting printed. I am changing the log level to INFO after starting the sparksession. I guess the directory is only created if it does not exist and maybe the directory is already present where the intermediate output would be spilt and hence no logs? Also, even though I am running the cluster on yarn why do I not have any LOCAL_DIRS env variable available but only a SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS? Your help is much appreciated

Comment: Hmmm can you set your logging level in `log4.properties` or `log4j2.properties` (depending on your spark version) instead of using `spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel('INFO')`? Doing the latter only sets your logging level after having decided what your local dirs are going to be.

Comment: I configured the logging by adding `log4j.logger.or.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer=INFO' at the end of my log4j.properties file
I am afraid I am not able to find the directory this way. Edited the question to show you what exactly my terminal is outputting after making the above mentioned change to the logging

Comment: Ahhh right I did not specify that well enough. With the line your tried out I think you have only set the logging level to INFO for the PythonGatewayServer. Putting `log4j.rootCategory=INFO, console` in your log4j.properties file is what I meant, which gives the needed logging level for all of your spark classes :) Or if you're on Spark version >= 3.3, `rootLogger.level = debug` in log4j2.properties.