# Why do spark workers write all tmp files, including shuffle and cache files, to different directories even though we define spark.local.dir?

Tags: apache-spark, ubuntu, pyspark, spark-submit

We are running Spark 3.5.0, PySpark 3.5.0 with 5 nodes in our cluster in client mode. The nodes in our cluster are using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

We were running into "No Space Left on Device" Errors caused Spark writing shuffle and cache files to the default /tmp on our worker nodes.

The problem: Only one of many nodes listens to spark.local.dir defined in spark-submit and SPARK_WORKER_OPTS defined in spark-env.sh.

We have tried to define `spark.local.dir` via 1) `spark-submit`, 2) `SparkConf().set()`, 3) `spark_defaults.conf` and `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` via 1) `spark-env.sh`, and 2) `--conf "spark.executorEnv.SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/mnt_path"`. In all cases, one of our nodes successfully writes to the defined path but the other nodes are writing to the default `/tmp`. Note, our defined path is a high-speed mounted volume shared with all of the nodes in our cluster.

Also, we have added the following to our `spark-env.sh`: `export SPARK_WORKER_OPTS="-Dspark.worker.cleanup.enabled=true -Dspark.worker.cleanup.interval=60 -Dspark.worker.cleanup.appDataTtl=60"` in hopes of removing work folders that are filling up our Root Volume. Again, this Environment variable is only working on one of our nodes.

Comment: Perhaps this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75018669/where-are-the-spark-intermediate-files-stored-on-the-disk/75020585#75020585 ?

Comment: This does help. My implementation:

```irdd = spark.sparkContext.range(0, 100, 1, 10)
    def wherearemydirs(p):
        import os
        import socket

        return (socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()), os.environ.get("SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS").split('/')[1])
print(set(irdd.map(wherearemydirs).collect()))
print(spark.sparkContext.getConf().get("spark.local.dir"))```

I didn't use LOCAL_DIRS as described in the post bc we are not running on Yarn. SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS is defined as tmp and spark.local.dir is the correct path. Is SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS is overwriting spark.local.dir?

Comment: Yes it does. You may want to check the other answer there which spells out the logic/order of preference followed by Spark.

Comment: Yes I did see across that. We are having issues setting SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS. We are setting `export SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/mnt/data_ebs/infrastructure/spark/tmp` in our spark-env.sh file but it does not seem to be doing the job. As shown above, within the map function, SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS is /tmp but when I print the same outside of the map function it is correct (/mnt/....)

Comment: Well... maybe you have `SPARK_EXECUTOR_DIRS` set to `/tmp`? Otherwise, setting `--conf "spark.executorEnv.SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS=/mnt_path"` should work.

Comment: The local directory that is used by the executors is provided by the Worker and the current Spark implementation does not allow for it to be set at the application level. Double check that `SPARK_EXECUTOR_DIRS` or `SPARK_LOCAL_DIR` is set in the `spark-env.sh` of the workers before starting them.

Comment: I have added `SPARK_EXECUTOR_DIRS` to our `spark-env.sh` file on each of the nodes in our cluster. At this point, both `SPARK_EXECUTOR_DIRS` and `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` are set in `spark-env.sh` using `export SPARK_EXECUTOR_DIRS=/mnt/path/to/tmp` for each respectively. Unfortunately, we are still getting shuffle files in `/tmp`